# Matlab error using find command

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, position, element

I have the vector `[0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1]`. I would like to find indices of 0 and 1s. I have tried using the `find` command, but I am getting:

```
0x1 empty double column vector
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add **the exact code you're using**, and what is the desired output in this case? What do you want to use it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [aahung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42885077/3372061) correctly returns the positions of the `0`'s and `1`'s, the typical use case for these indices would be choosing elements from another array that match these positions. If this is indeed the case, one should rely on logical indexing **instead of** `find`:

```
tfArr = [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1];
data =  reshape(magic(3),1,[]); % [8,3,4,1,5,9,6,7,2]

dataWhereOnes = data(logical(tfArr))
% equivalently to the above : data(~~tfArr)
dataWhereZeros = data(~tfArr)
```

Which results in:

```
dataWhereOnes =
     4     1     9     6     2

dataWhereZeros =
     8     3     5     7
```

Comment: its easy to look for the positions here but what if it is a 1000 element vector

Comment: No difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you:

```
>> arr = [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1];
>> find(arr == 0)

ans =

     1     2     5     8

>> find(arr == 1)

ans =

     3     4     6     7     9
```

Comment: i have tried this but i get an error as in question

Comment: Plz post your *codes* and error, or we cannot help you